# Election page for non-existent election gives misleading result

Tags: bug, status-completed, election

Currently there is an election on Super User. It is the fourth, reachable via https://superuser.com/election/4 .

The URLs `https://superuser.com/election/<election-id>` correctly gives the pages of the earlier elections. https://superuser.com/election correctly gives the page of the ongoing election.

But, going to the URL of a non-existent election (for example, https://superuser.com/election/6 ), I get this:

[image: "There are no active community moderator elections at the moment. Below is a historical record of all elections to date:"]

> There are no active community moderator elections at the moment. Below
>   is a historical record of all elections to date:

Which is false, because there is an ongoing election at the moment.

Also I don't think it would be the bug of the century, although I think you want to make everything perfect on the site. :-)

Comment: You could even argue it should return the [/404](https://superuser.com/404) page.

Comment: @rene 404 looks so... depressing. Maybe a 302 redirect to the election list. I don't think it would be our decision :-)

Comment: yeah, sure. but for consistency 404 is better.

Comment: @rene Or, maybe: "This community election wasn't started until now." or similar, probably with better English :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been fixed; https://superuser.com/election/6 now leads to the familiar 404 page:

[image]

(It also works this way on sites with an ongoing election: check https://apple.stackexchange.com/election/6)